# How to block guest from downloading files

Tags: php

I have this tiny code to make only members can download 20 files per day,

If they exceed the limit a page will show up to warn and block them.

Everything work great for now, **but what I'm trying to do is to make guest users show different msg like "only members can download" if they try to download anything. How I can achieve that!**

Note: All members that not login into the system named "guest"

```
if (!(isset($_GET['username']) && !empty($_GET['username']))){
   echo 'Only a member of this website can download this file. However, no username was specified in this download. Sorry for inconvenience.';  
   die;
}

$dl_username = $this->decrypt($_GET['username']);

if (gator::getUser($dl_username) == false){
    echo 'Only a member of this website can download this file. However, the username provided does not exist in the database. Sorry for inconvenience.';   
    die;
}

$dl_user = gator::getUser($dl_username);
if ($dl_user['downloads'] > 20){
   echo 'Cannot download more files for today! You have crossed the limit of downloading 20 files.';
   die;
}
```

Comment: what is the `gator` class? Surely you just make a function that checks if the user is logged in? If not, echo a message? seems like a barely basic concept...

Comment: Your `gator` needs to tell you what the user type, user rights, or user role is so you can tell a guest apart from a normal user.  Also, you should set $dl_user first and check that for == false instead of calling `gator::getUser` twice.

Comment: I want to check if the value is "false" or "guest" to block the downloud, that's my problem how do I add "guest" too! yes It's very basic qustion about OR statment

Comment: any user that's not login named "guest" the gator name it like that

Comment: "if (gator::getUser($dl_username) == false)" I want to add or guest here, I don;t know how to use or here on this line!

Comment: but surely if it equals false, that means the user can't be found, therefor its not a valid user and you can assume they are not logged in

Comment: this is too assumptive - add your gator class

Comment: `$_GET['username']`  What's to stop me from using someone else's account to download my 20 files?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I just notice this security bug, it's so danguerus I don't know how to cover it! if someone changed the link to another username it can download, any hint to solve that!

Comment: Use the session instead.